# Recover Win 8 from HDD connected with USB

Tags: windows, ssd, system-recovery

I have installed an SSD to my Lenovo Y50-70 computer. I am trying to use recovery partition to reinstall windows on SSD from my old HDD. I think I can access recovery menu from my old HDD connected via USB but I fear that it will try to install Windows to HDD on USB again and I lose my files. And the windows recovery menu doesn't really give any options, but just jumps to copying files. That's when I force shutdown the PC. Can anyone help with any advice please?

Comment: Why not make an image of your old HDD then write the image to the SSD. this is how normal conversions would work.

Comment: This would surely work but immigrating from a 1TB HDD to 256 gb SSD, this is not a good option. Anyhow I did it buy a tool on the Microsoft site which copied my license and installed a clean win10. Just search for "Download win10 iso" on google. I lost my recovery disk but it works so great.